# HERE MAPS Map matching API documentation

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest

im using `m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/matchroute.json` endpoint to mapmatch GPS traces.
The result provides values like:

```
[1] "lat"                                           "lon"                                          
[3] "document.2..TracePoints.confidenceValue"       "document.2..TracePoints.matchDistance"        
[5] "document.2..TracePoints.minError"              "document.2..TracePoints.linkIdMatched"        
[7] "document.2..TracePoints.routeLinkSeqNrMatched" "document.2..TracePoints.matchOffsetOnLink"    
[9] "document.2..TracePoints.linkIdMatched.1"
```

Its kind of silly question but i seem not to be able to find a description of those parameters anywhere anymore.
I know the documentation was available not long before.
Are those parameters deprecated and there will no longer be a service or where could i find a documentation of those?

thank you.
Andreas

Comment: Hi Andreas, 
In order to help you we will need more information about this case, we have tried to find the values you have shared with us but we cannot find them in our [documentation][1], this service as you can see in our page is "In Maintenance".
Can you please share the request you are using with us, and the use case if possible?

  [1]: https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html

Comment: Sure: i would like to match a custom trace and see the confidence of matches for each point. It was definitely possible before and apparently still possible. This is the request:       "https://m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/matchroute.json?routemode=car&maneuverattributes=position,link&linkattributes=shape,DynamicSpeedInfo&apiKey=",  As Body i supply a GPX file. Im using this service to remove "bad" points which would lead me for example against the road direction. .. I knew i should have saved the pdf ...